# struct becomes NULL

Tags: c, struct, tree, linked-list

I wanted to implement a OOP-like implementation of linked-lists.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    char data[100];
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
}Node;

typedef struct treeNode {
    char treeData[100];
    struct treeNode *left;
    struct treeNode *right;
}TreeNode;

typedef struct sql_struct{
    Node *head, *tail;
}StackQueueList;

typedef struct tree {
    TreeNode *root;
}Tree;

void initStackQueueList(StackQueueList* a) {
    a->head = a->tail = NULL;
}///initStackQueueList

Tree* initTree (Tree* a) {
    a->root = NULL;
}///newTree
```

But the problem is whenever I use the `initStackQueueList()` it always make it seem that the pointer is `NULL` which kinda makes sense because I wanted the VALUES inside it be null, just not the POINTER itself be null. So probably, I implemented something wrong here and I can't wrap my head around it so I'm asking for help! :)

Sample implementation:

```
static const StackQueueList *dqFriend1, *dqFriend2, *dqMyself, *dqVirus;

void initQueues () {
    initStackQueueList(dqFriend1);
    initStackQueueList(dqFriend2);
    initStackQueueList(dqMyself);
    initStackQueueList(dqVirus);
}
```

=Corrected Version=

```
StackQueueList *dqFriend1, *dqFriend2, *dqMyself, *dqVirus;
*dqFriend1 = *dqFriend2 = *dqMyself = *dqVirus = (StackQueueList*) malloc(sizeof (StackQueueList));

void initQueues () {
    initStackQueueList(dqFriend1);
    initStackQueueList(dqFriend2);
    initStackQueueList(dqMyself);
    initStackQueueList(dqVirus);
}
```

But now I'm experiencing these errors:

```
error: conflicting types for 'dqFriend1'|
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'StackQueueList' from type 'struct StackQueueList *'|
```

Comment: this would be a good time to use the debugger, with a 'watch' of the variable that is giving the problem.

Comment: in general, when some function is expected to fill in a pointer to some data, it is usual to pass the address of the pointer variable, NOT the contents of the pointer variable.  suggest: initStackQueueList( &dqFriend1 );

Comment: just for safety, the declaration of the pointers should initialize them to NULL.  and it is clearest if each pointer is declared on a separate line.

Comment: in C, struct definitions should not be wrapped in a typedef.  The typedef obscures/clutters the code and clutters the compiler name space.

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for the tip. I'll try that at a later time but I'm currently trying to fix the issue, which as pointed out by people here I'm actually really passing a NULL struct because i forgot to allocate memory for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allocate space for pointers `dqFriend1`, `dqFriend2`, `dqMyself`, `dqVirus` first. Otherwise there will be no place for their members.

```
eg. dqFriend1 = (StackQueueList*)malloc(sizeof(StackQueueList));
```

Comment: I actually used the watch utility, the value is 0x0 which means the  StackQueryList is null. Good catch! But I'm experiencing an issue with a conflicting error type when I do that. Any ideas to resolve this?

Comment: Thanks @PatJ! Removing the pointer before the variables did the trick! Hahaha.